# Lost my Unity sidebar / dock

Tags: unity, dock

I did a quite drastic removal of packages from my Ubuntu, and seem to have lost the sidebar / dock in Unity. The desktop icons are still there and work, but there's no way to launch applications from the side-bar or get to the terminal.

What's the name of the program / package so I can reinstall it?

Update : actually it's worse than this. I seem to have lost the ability to tab between different windows, and all the necessary Window maximize / minimize / close buttons in the "chrome" of the browser are gone too. How can I restore these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get a terminal Window by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or executing "gnome-terminal" in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> HUD.
If those two also disappeared, you have to use the TTY1 full-screen terminal. You get there by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. You get back to the graphical surface (TTY7) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. In the TTY, you have to login first by manually entering your username and password. After that you may run any command you want.

I am not sure which packages you have removed or which packages are needed to get back these basic functionalities, but I would think that reinstalling *ubuntu-desktop* would be a good start.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop --reinstall
```

Comment: Yes, that reinstall of ubuntu-desktop was exactly what I needed. What I'd (rather foolishly) done was try to apt-get remove python2.7 from my machine. A hell of a lot of dependent functionality went with it.

Comment: Nice to read that I could help you. Next time you should read through the list of packages that is going to be removed before saying yes and amen... :)